# How to use c# code inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am new to javascript. i would like to write asp.net code using script. using the code shown below doesn't give any output.or should i use ajax to access asp.net file

**here my sample code : a.html**

```
<script runat="server" language="c#" type="text/c#">

 protected void Page_Load(Object s, EventArgs e){

    Response.Write("Welcome to our web site.");

}

</script>

<body>

</body>
```

Comment: Based on the way you framed your question and the code you provided, I think your first step is to distinguish what is "asp.net" vs "javascript".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access C# code,you have to write Webmethod...

You have to place a scriptmanager..

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>

 [WebMethod]
    public static string Abc()
    {
    }
```

You can access the C# method in script as follows..

```
function Test()
{
PageMethods.Abc(onSucess, onError);

        function onSucess(result) {
          alert("Success");
        }
        function onError(result) {
            alert('Cannot process your request at the moment, please try later....');
        }
        return false;
}
```